# Python Spyder IPython console set width

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder

Is it possible to set Spyder's IPython console horizontally scrollable like Jupyter Notebook's IPython cells? I know that I can set pandas options (eg. `pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)` and `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)`), but in this case my last columns's rows are under my first columns's rows. And I want the columns next to each other in one line.

Thank you!

Comment: I would also like to see an answer but I doubt it is possible.

Comment: I'm interested in any alternatives like "use Jupyter Notebooks or PyCharm" or "use two (or three) wide monitors" ;-)